# Могу ли я сделать вывод программы на Python цветным?

Tags: python, color, windows

Хочу например чтоб строки вида, а точнее их вывод в консоль:

```
print 'Hello World'
```

Были зеленого цвета. Это возможно? Подскажите как?

Comment: Где? (Операционная система, графический/текстовый режим и т.д.)

Comment: ОС Linux, Windows - графичский режим. Окно терминала.

Comment: @toorook а ответ @Ilya Pirogov чем Вам не нравится?

Comment: связанный вопрос [Print in terminal with colors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/287871/4279)

Comment: Можете попробовать [эту библиотеку](https://github.com/jieggiI/pictorem)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используются ANSCII escape symbols, некоторые из них отвечают за цвета. В большинстве терминалов Linux они поддерживаются. Можно просто погуглить на эту тему и не обязательно скачивать colorama, хотя, наверняка, это упростит работу.

Просто проверьте и всё.

```
import sys
import time
import random

string = "123456789\n"

def color(text):
    sys.stdout.write(u"\x1B[{0}m{1}\x1B[0m".format
                                 (random.choice(range(31,36)+
                                               range(90,97)),i))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(random.random()/6)

for i in string:
    color(i)
```

Answer (score 17):

[colorama](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama)

> Cross-platform colored terminal text.

Answer (score 4):

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/termcolor попробуй библиотеку;)И в использовании легче

```
from termcolor import colored

print(colored('Hello World!', 'green')
```

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы не вводить руками [ANSI коды](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_ANSI) для цветов и смены текущей позиции, [`blessings`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/blessings) пакет может быть использован:

```
from blessings import Terminal # $ pip install blessings
import colorama # $ pip install colorama
colorama.init() # replace ANSI escapes with Win32 calls in stdout/stderr

t = Terminal()
with t.location(0, t.height - 1): # at the bottom of the terminal
    print(t.green('Hello World'))
```

[`colorama`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama), предложенная [@Ilya Pirogov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/294616/23044), позволяет одному и тому же коду работать как на Linux, OS X, других Unices так и Windows.