# Выделение отдельных букв в слове

Tags: python

Добрый день подскажите, как реализовать следующее:
Необходимо в слове находить определенные сочетания букв и в дальнейшем при выводе этого слова, эти сочетания букв подсвечивались другим цветом или делать их жирными. Например:  powerful  необходимо найти ow и ful. Результат должен быть  p**ow**er**ful**.

```
word = "powerful"
edd_word = []
for w in word:
    edd_word.append(w)
if "o" and "w" in edd_word:
    # необходимо добавить исполняемую часть чтобы выделила сочетание OW
if "f" and "u" and "l" in edd_word:
    # необходимо добавить исполняемую часть чтобы выделила сочетание FUL
print () #вывод самого слова с выделенными частями.
```

Как реализовать это?

Comment: в чём у вас сложности? Как индекс подстроки найти в строке? Как подсветить подстроку по указанным индексам? (лучше отдельно эти вопросы задать—поиск и раскрашивание не связаны) Вы хотите в терминале цвета получить?

Comment: Сложности: Как подсветить подстроку по указанным индексам?

Comment: в комментарии к собственному вопросу не помещайте информацию необходимую для ответа. Обновите ваш вопрос вместо этого, нажмите [edit]

Comment: связанный вопрос [Могу ли я сделать вывод программы на Python цветным?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/294557/23044)