# Вернуться на предыдущую строку в консоли

Tags: python, консоль

Для возврата каретки есть `\r`. Однако он не может перенести её на предыдущую строку.
Очистка всего экрана и запись заново в моём случае полный не вариант.
Так как же вернуть вывод на предыдущую строку без `(n)curses` и `system('cls')`?

Comment: много ответов уже давали [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/715566/Очистка-консоли-после-каждого-принта)

Comment: связанный вопрос [Могу ли я сделать вывод программы на Python цветным?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/294557/23044)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для этого можно подходящую [управляющую последовательность ANSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_sequences) вывести (что даже на Windows можно включить или эмулировать с помощью [`сolorama` модуля](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama)). Вы выводите в терминал специальную последовательность байт, которая изменяет текущую позицию курсора. В моём окружении можно вывести `ESC [ A` (в Питоне: `b'\x1b[A'`) последовательность, чтобы вверх на строчку курсор передвинуть в терминале:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import curses
import os
import sys
import time

# http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcurses/terminfo.html
curses.setupterm()
UP = curses.tigetstr('cuu1')  # Upline(cursor up)

fd = sys.stdout.fileno()
for data in [b'a', b'b', b'\n', b'de', b'fg', UP, b'X', b'Y']:
    os.write(fd, data)
    time.sleep(.5)
```

Скрипт демонстрирует, что вывод `UP` последовательности поднимает курсор на строчку.

[image: terminal session]