# Изменение местоположения курсора в консоли Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, python-3.5

Как на Python 3 с Windows 8.1 изменять местоположение мигающего курсора в консоли?
Например, мне нужно вывести "foo"  в консоль, передвинуть курсор на 1 строку вверх и написать "!" (чтобы получилось "!oo")?

Этот код не работает:

```
import colorama
colorama.init()

print("foo")      # Выводит: foo
print("\033[F!")  #          !
```

Comment: Попробуйте `print("foo"); print("\033[1A!")` (должно вывести `!oo`)

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Вернуться на предыдущую строку в консоли](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/782307/23044)

Comment: попробуйте работает ли для вас демо с именами (предпочтительный вариант): https://github.com/tartley/colorama/blob/master/demos/demo07.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from ctypes import *

STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11

class COORD(Structure):
    pass

COORD._fields_ = [("X", c_short), ("Y", c_short)]

def print_at(r, c, s):
    h = windll.kernel32.GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)
    windll.kernel32.SetConsoleCursorPosition(h, COORD(c, r))

    c = s.encode("cp866")
    windll.kernel32.WriteConsoleA(h, c_char_p(c), len(c), None, None)


print_at(6, 3, "Hello")
```

[Отсюда](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Terminal_control/Cursor_positioning#Python)

Comment: Спасибо! Нигде не мог найти решения!

Comment: @Bamberghh [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: cp866 выглядит неверно. ANSI codepage для `*A()` API используется. `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` (пример: cp1251). Лучше Юникодное WriteConsoleW() API использовать, не кодируя в байты. Ещё лучше попробовать код типа `demo07.py` упомянутый выше.

Comment: @jfs как ни странно, но на моей машине только при использовании cp866 результат нормальный.

Comment: под нормальным вы только про ascii строки говорите?

Comment: @jfs если я возьму этот код, поменяю в нём строку "Hello" на "Привет" и запущу с помощью Python3, то во всех случаях, кроме использования cp866, в консоль будут выведены кракозябры.

Comment: Нашёл цитату, которая подтверждает, что не смотря на A суффикс (который подразумевает ANSI, к примеру  cp1251 кодировку), консольные функции принимают OEM codepage, к примеру, cp866: *"The "A" versions of the console functions accept characters in the OEM code page despite the "A" suffix that would suggest ANSI."*  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20051027-37/?p=33593/

Comment: значит пример, с которого вы скопировали ошибочен: вместо cp1252, там cp437 должно использоваться